# Is Be, Do and Have all we can talk about?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have heard that theoretically you can classify all things you can possibly talk/write about into 3 categories i.e. be, do and have. People and things can be something, do something and have something, but that is it. (Beliefs, experiences and intentions fall under the Have category; we have beliefs, experiences and intentions.)

What is the significance of this? Is it true (is it possible to categorize all sentences into these 3 categories with nothing left over)?

Comment: I'm trying to think of instances where something can be classified as neither of these three things... Good question, but is about the English language (belief=have) or something grander and philosophical?

Comment: I do not understand the classification. If I *have* a car, that's also what I *do*. Likewise for *be*, actually. What is the point of this excercise? I am not quite sure how we can be expected to comment on the significance of something so random. Also, what is these "things" we can possibly talk/write about? You don't define that. If I say "ouch", "wow", "huh?" or "goddamn", I am most certainly talking, and yet these things are most certainly not do, not be, and not have.

Comment: @RegDwighт  "Ouch" "wow" etc. are different experiences and hence "be". It's not easy to think of exceptions, I gave up after two minutes. Leave it open it might generate some interesting discussion.

Comment: Possibly useless, but someone might have found some use for this pattern of language. I would speculate that ouch, wow and huh are not proper sentences but rather expression similar to things we can express with body language. I've also spotted that many things can be expressed as all of them e.g. 'I have money' therefore 'I am rich' and can 'spend money'(do). I 'have a belief' which 'make me a certain type of person' who 'does certain things'. Maybe anything which can be expressed in one of these categories will necessarily have meaningful expressions to be found in the others? Maybe...???

Comment: At first blush, your three categories could be apt. Link past, present, and future to them.  1) BE and PAST. Things and creatures come into being, and when they can be said to BE, they have a history.  2) HAVE and PRESENT.  To have something tangible and/or intangible is to have it in the PRESENT, even if the notion of the present is evanescent (as soon as it's here, it's gone!)  DO and FUTURE.  Each and every act or movement ("people act; things move") is in the process of acting and/or moving. A "to do list" is never completed.  Even when creatures die, they do something:  decompose!

Comment: I'm afraid this is some teacher's inspiration for students, and not really a serious proposition. _Do_ has about a dozen uses, _have_ and _be_ considerably more. None of them have any real literal meaning; they're semantically bleached by all the heavy grammar lifting they do. Indeed, it's dangerous to believe they should "mean something"; mostly they mean nothing and are just there to mark some particular construction. As words, they're pretty nondescript; as categories, they're hopeless.

Comment: Surely this is more of a philosophical question ("What is the significance of this?") than a language question?

Comment: First of all, Kriss, of course "Wow!", "Huh?" and "Ouch!" are proper sentences. More to the point though, I wasn't talking about sentences, and neither were you. You only ever mentioned talking; that it must be in sentences is an all-new constraint. Secondly, @Mari-LouA: you say "ouch" and "wow" are experiences, and thus Be. However, Kriss quite clearly states that experiences fall under the Have category. So again, these are several reasons right there why this question is on hold. Clarification is in order. Not to mention that I second John's and Trevor's points.

Comment: Yep, @RegDwighт I was wrong about the "be" part, it should have been "have", but even those utterances can be classified according to the rules set up by the OP. I think you're missing an opportunity for the community to either openly agree or dissect The OP's argument. BUT, as I said in my first comment, it is not really a question based on language but on opinions and ideas.

Comment: @JohnLawler Surely there is a literal meaning to do, be and have. 'Do' is about movement, 'be' is about identity/existence, and 'have' is about ownership (or something similar). Are you saying that there is no chance there is a theory out there and that there will never be a theory of language/grammar/writing who uses a similar categorisation to describe, clarify, predict or explain something useful to students, writers and teachers alike? What about the obvious connection between do and verbs, be and nouns, have and ??? .....??????

Comment: One sense of _do_ is 'to act'; it's a proverb for active verbs: _What he did was build a house_. Not for stative verbs: _*What he did was own a house_. One sense of _have_ is 'to possess', but it's not the most common use. And there is no literal meaning of _be_; it's always an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @RegDwighт Aren't all 3 fundamental auxiliary verbs in some sense? There are other auxiliary verbs, like can, will, should, etc, but they cannot stand alone in the sense that be, do and have can; they always add something additional on top of either be, do or have e.g. 'I can do', 'I will have', 'I should eat food'. In the last case (I should eat food) I'm not using 'do' but that is the meaning i.e. I should do x. 'Be' might not mean something by itself, but 'I am strong' is not the same as 'I strong'. Maybe these 3 are a base for semantics? Surely it is a relevant question for this forum?